# Editing Group Policies with Python in Win XP

Tags: python, registry

Is there any way to change group policies or edit them with Python?

I know registry can be edited, but I dont have any idea about editing or modifying group policy. I have here 100 PC on which some plocies has to be set like, denying access to folder options, denying access to control panel, computers are not a part of domain. so I am given this task to modify the policies on every computer.

Some automated Python Scripts would save a lot of time for me.

> ( OS: Win XP, Python2.7 )